# How to solve this indefinite integral? $\int {t}{\sqrt{1+\cos(t)}} \,dt$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, radicals, substitution

I tried solving the following integral:

$\int {(t+\sin(t))}{\sqrt{1+\cos(t)}} \,dt$

I split the problem in two parts.

The first part gave me this:

$\int {\sin(t)}{\sqrt{1+\cos(t)}} \,dt = -\frac{2}{3}{(1+\cos(t))}^{\frac{3}2}+c$

I didn't know how to solve the second part:

$\int {t}{\sqrt{1+\cos(t)}} \,dt$

I tried substitution but couldn't find a way to integrate

Comment: Straightforward:  $$2 \sqrt{\cos (t)+1} \left(t \tan \left(\frac{t}{2}\right)+2\right)$$

Comment: Did you substitute using u = tan(t/2) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**

You may be interested in the following identity:
\begin{align*}
1 + \cos(t) = 2\cos^{2}\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)
\end{align*}

Hence the proposed integral reduces to
\begin{align*}
\int t\sqrt{1 + \cos(t)}\mathrm{d}t = \pm\sqrt{2}\int t\cos\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\mathrm{d}t
\end{align*}

which can be easily solved through IBP.

Can you take it from here?